# How to compare 1 point cloud data with 1 or more point cloud data?

Tags: visual-c++, point-clouds

I want to compare a point cloud data(.pcd , .ply file) with 1 or more point cloud data and want to get similar points or patches. So I want to know which technique or algorithm has to be used?

Comment: Your question is too generic. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What will you use the `similar points and patches` once you identified them?

Comment: E.g. do you want to do object recognition?

Comment: Try CloudCompare (http://www.danielgm.net/cc/), it might be the right tool for your task.

Comment: thank you very much. i am working on hole filling of point cloud data using exemplar . so actually want to compare point clouds and get matching ones and use them for interpolation in hole. i tried correspondence_grouping but getting errors as .h files(boost.h,pcl\recognition\cg\correspondence_grouping.h,pcl\recognition\impl\correspondence_grouping.h) are missing. i looked for them in pcl 1.6.0 they were missing i tried to find them in github got some and didn't got some other(boost.h). what would be problem.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is:

1. **Feature point detection:** Find points on the surface of a point cloud that have a very unique and descriptive neighbourhood.
2. **Feature estimation:** For these points and their neighbours (usually in spherical radius R) compute a descriptor. This can be a histogram, a simple value or a multi dimensional vector. Depends on the descriptor you're using.
3. **Find correspondences:** Now for both point clouds, compare these descriptors and find matching ones (these are correspondences) and try to find these correspondences in a way that one point cloud fits the other. Reject correspondences that do not match.

If two clouds have a set of matching correspondences you can say that these two are certainly similiar.

I'd suggest to use the Point Clouds Library (PCL). There's a pretty good tutorial here:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php#correspondence-grouping

Also there is an overview of feature algorithms here (not complete though):

https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/wiki/Overview-and-Comparison-of-Features

Comment: thank you very much. i am working on hole filling of point cloud data using exemplar . so actually want to compare point clouds and get matching ones and use them for interpolation in hole. i tried correspondence_grouping but getting errors as .h files(boost.h,pcl\recognition\cg\correspondence_grouping.h,pcl\recognition\impl\correspondence_grouping.h) are missing. i looked for them in pcl 1.6.0 they were missing i tried to find them in github got some and didn't got some other(boost.h). what would be problem.??

Comment: Try not to use the all in one installer. Build PCL from the repository (https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl). There are tutorials how to build PCL from source on their page (like this for windows: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_windows.php#compiling-pcl-windows)